# Can you get the snowflake status notification by webhook?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, webhooks

ppl.

I would like to get the slack status notification to the teams channel.
Altough I set the teams webhook url on the site: https://status.snowflake.com/#, I haven't get the notification.
I also set the slack webhook url on the site, and as well I haven't although I get the notification from the slack snowfalke-status app.

I think the snowflake status webhook doesn't work. Are there anyone can get the notification by the webhoook?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you’re using one of the methods shown here - which one, and how are you invoking for status updates?  https://status.snowflake.com/api

Comment: I just set webhook subscripiton by "SUBSCRIBE TO UPDATE" in the page:https://status.snowflake.com/#. So, I don't make or use an API application.
About Teams webhook making, I did by this way:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook

Comment: Will webhooks  work with an Atlassian Statuspsge?  Im not seeing anything in the documentation that leads me to believe you’ll receive updates this way.

Comment: I found in the atlassian community that the atlassian don't support teams webhook notification. I gave up to use it. Thank you Jim.
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Statuspage-questions/Failed-to-add-webhook-url-of-Microsoft-Teams-when-subscribing/qaq-p/1734260

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the confirmation from the comments that Snowflake's status page is built off of an Atlassian Status page, which does not support webhook notifications:  https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Statuspage-questions/Failed-to-add-webhook-url-of-Microsoft-Teams-when-subscribing/qaq-p/1734260